# I have a list of dictionaries in my json, I want to use it in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, dictionary

My json is looking like this :

```
[  
{
    "statCount": 5,
    "inceptionStat": [
      {
        "1": "name1",
        "2": "name2",
        "3": "name3",
        "4": "name4",
        "5": "name5"
      }
    ]
  },  
{"statCount": 2,
 "inceptionStat": 
[
      {
        "1": "name1",
        "2": "name2"
      }
    ]
  },  
{
    "statCount": 0,
    "inceptionStat": [
      {}
    ]
  }

]
```

I want to use inceptionStat arrays in angularjs to create a list of all my names, I tried multiple things but I did not find a way to print only name1, name2 and so on for each statCount.

I used some javascript to isolate inceptionStat data :

```
 $scope.result = $($scope.data).map(function () {
            return this.inceptionStat;
        }).get()
        console.log($scope.result);
```

$scope.data here is the entire json data.

So from here, I tried to use ng-repeat to create my list of names from my different arrays object but I did not find the correct way I guess.

Is there an easy way to do that ?

Comment: Can you show *how* you tried to use `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="dictionary in dictionaries">
  <h4>statcount: {{dictionary.statCount}}</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in dictionary.inceptionStat[0]">{{value}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With the JSON:

```
$scope.dictionaries = [
  {
    "statCount": 5,
    "inceptionStat": [
      {
        "1": "name1",
        "2": "name2",
        "3": "name3",
        "4": "name4",
        "5": "name5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "statCount": 2,
    "inceptionStat": [
      {
        "1": "name1",
        "2": "name2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "statCount": 0,
    "inceptionStat": [
      {}
    ]
  }
];
```

The `inceptionStat[0]` has the zero in it because your `inceptionStat` is an object, not an array.

Comment: That's it, thank you for your help. I was missing the [0] !

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!